# trying to style the shadow DOM from outside

Tags: javascript, html, css, shadow-dom

I'm trying to style the text in the shadow dom without success. The only thing is that I want to do it from outside the shadow DOM. An other important thing, the Shadow dom styling should only apply to the shadow dom inside a 'bar' element. Here is my test code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      :host(bar) span:first-child {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: green;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <bar></bar>

    <script>
      var bar = document.querySelector('bar');
      var root = bar.createShadowRoot();
      root.innerHTML = '<span>bar</span><span>foo</span>';
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And a bonus question, what exactly does

```
:host(bar:host) { ... }
```

do ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shadow DOM specification is currently still in development, most of its functionality is radically changing from one moment to the next.

To style a shadow DOM element from the outside it depends on if your browser relies on the (outdated) peusdo-element exposure or the new css shadow dom selectors `^^` (cat) and `^` (hat)
If the browser supports the new syntax, you can simply enter an elements shadow dom using the hat (`^`) selector, or if you wish to cross all shadow boundaries, you can use the cat (`^^`) selector to do so.

If the browser does not yet support it, you need to expose the element you wish to style as a pseudo-element of its parent by adding the pseudo attribute to it, `<shadow-element peusdo="myname" />`, and then reference that pseudo element in your css `shadow-host::myname`

As to your 'bonus' question, you are referencing the shadow host element, but only if the shadow host is a `<bar>` element, if you omit the second `:host` you are referencing a shadow host that is a `<bar>` element or has one as its ancestor.

Do note that because the API is in constant development, the above information may not remain reliable beyond more then a month or so.

Comment: nice, thnx. I just noticed that **bar ^ span { ... }** does work, but  **bar ^ span:first-child { ... }** does not (Chrome v34). That probably has to do with all this being 'experimental'

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri CSS order in a shadow dom is rather shady right now, so if you wish to target the first span you might wish to try `span:first-of-type` instead, and wrapping your shadow dom HTML in a parent element might also fix a lot of issues.

Comment: I tried the parent node suggestion which indeed fixed it, thnx. I tried to use a [polyfill](https://github.com/Polymer/ShadowDOM) too, but that doesn't seem to work at all. Do they not support the **^** in css ?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri shadow DOM cant be duplicated by polyfills, its a whole new design implementation (new HTML nodes, new CSS classes pseudo-classes and selectors, new javascript methods etc.) its simply to complex and to big to polyfill properly.

Comment: has /deep/ gone away?

Comment: @MichaelMullany Recently the shadow-piercing `/deep/` combinator was changed to `>>>` [Check out the latest version of the spec.](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-scoping/#deep-combinator)